# Deep Link Base URL - error: Can not convert an object of type

Tags: android, genexus, genexus-sd

I'm having trouble implementing the deep link in Genexus.
I am using the U8 version of Genexus 15 in .NET with an offline application and some objects online.

When I enter the url where the application is hosted and will count the webpanels that will refer to the SD object in the "Deep Link Base URL" property, I get the following information:

```
'========== Build lasttime started ==========
========== Copying Module 'GeneXus' started ==========
Copying Module 'GeneXus' Success
========== Integrated Security Initialization started ==========
Integrated Security Initialization Success
========== GAM Applications Registration started ==========
No new applications for registration.
GAM Applications Registration Success
Processing lasttime
========== Target Environment update started ==========
Target Environment update Success
Building changed objects list
========== Specification started ==========
 Specifying lasttime_Level_Detail_Grid1 ...
warning spc0038: There is no index for order (eventoData); poor performance may be noticed in grid Grid1. (Panel for Smart Devices 'lasttime', Details)
Generating Resources...Processing inferred calls...
Success
========== Default (C# Web) Generation started ==========
Specification Success
Generating Resources...Success
Generating to NET\web\lasttime_level_detail_grid1.cs
Generating to NET\web\lasttime_level_detail_grid1.svc
Generating to NET\web\gxrowlevelcache.cs
Generating to NET\web\gxcfg.js
Generating to NET\web\GXCFG.WEB
Generating to NET\web\client.exe.config
Generating to NET\web\WCFClient.config
Generating to NET\web\gxmetadata\gxversion.json
Generating to NET\web\bldDevelopermenu.cs
Generating to NET\web\bldlasttime.cs
Generating to NET\web\runsets.ini
Generating to NET\web\genexus.programs.common.rsp
Generating to NET\web\exe.bld
Generating to NET\web\winexe.bld
Generating to NET\web\library.bld
Generating to NET\web\bld15.info
Default (C# Web) Generation Success
Compressing static files...Success
========== SmartDevices (Smart Devices) Generation started ==========
Generating metadata files...
Writing metadata for lasttime (android)
Applying Root Project
Applying Bootstrapping for:lasttime
Generating Android theme styles...
error: Não é possível converter um objeto do tipo Artech.Genexus.Common.CustomTypes.FileType no tipo System.String.
SmartDevices (Smart Devices) Generation Failed
Build lasttime Failed'
```

Has anyone had this problem or was it already able to use the deep link without problems?

Log in windows event viewer:

```
'Timestamp: 17/01/2018 23:47:23
Message: HandlingInstanceID: ca46dd55-a9d6-4400-b571-826b0b8e6628
An exception of type Artech.Common.Diagnostics.GxException occurred and was caught.
01/17/2018 23:47:23
Type : Artech.Common.Diagnostics.GxException, Artech.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6f5bf81c27b6b8aa
Message : Não é possível converter um objeto do tipo Artech.Genexus.Common.CustomTypes.FileType no tipo System.String.
Source : 
Help link : 
Exception Data
Product : GeneXus 15
Version : 15.0.119728 U8
Exception.Severity : Warning
TargetSite : 
HResult : -2146232832
Stack Trace : The stack trace is unavailable.
Additional Info:

MachineName : GABRIEL-HP
TimeStamp : 18/01/2018 01:47:23
FullName : Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=79a65ef946496ecc
AppDomainName : GeneXus.exe
ThreadIdentity : GABRIEL-HP\Gabriel Mariano
WindowsIdentity : GABRIEL-HP\Gabriel Mariano
    Inner Exception
    ---------------
    Type : System.InvalidCastException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
    Message : Não é possível converter um objeto do tipo Artech.Genexus.Common.CustomTypes.FileType no tipo System.String.
    Source : Artech.Common.Properties
    Help link : 
    TargetSite : T GetPropertyValue[T](System.String)
    HResult : -2147467262
    Stack Trace :    at Artech.Common.Properties.PropertiesObject.GetPropertyValue[T](String propName)
       at Artech.Generator.SmartDevices.CustomGenerators.AndroidCreateAssetLinks.KSDsdhn36l()
       at Artech.Generator.SmartDevices.CustomGenerators.AndroidCreateAssetLinks.Generate(Object data, IDictionary`2 context)
       at Artech.Generators.GeneratorEngine.<>c__DisplayClass29_0.<RunInstanceSpecificGenerators>b__0(FilterAndGenerator gen)
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.TrueForAll(Predicate`1 match)
       at Artech.Generators.GeneratorInstance.ApplyStrategies(GeneratorApply[] strategies, IDictionary`2 context)
       at Artech.Generators.GeneratorEngine.ApplyStrategies(String target, IObjectListCommand data, IDictionary`2 context)


Category: Default Category
Priority: 0
EventId: 100
Severity: Warning
Title:Genexus Application Exception
Machine: GABRIEL-HP
Application Domain: GeneXus.exe
Process Id: 5836
Process Name: C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus15\GeneXus.exe
Win32 Thread Id: 11504
Thread Name: InProcessDaemon-26
Extended Properties: AdvancedInformation.Product - GeneXus 15
AdvancedInformation.Version - 15.0.119728 U8
Exception.Severity - Warning'
```

Comment: Could you provide some extra lines of the output so that I can see on what file you get that error ?

Comment: I updated the question with all the output.

If I remove the url from the property the build occurs without problems

Comment: thanks! could you add info of stack trace that is in the event viewer ?

Comment: do you mean windows event viewer? If it is, it is attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an error in GeneXus, [ref.: SAC 42801](https://www.genexus.com/developers/websac?es,,,42801). It has been already fixed. Fix will be available first in GeneXus Tero Beta Channel (build 120455 or higher) and then also in [GeneXus Preview Channel](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?28877,GeneXus%20Preview%20Channel,). Thank you for reporting!

Comment: Build 120511 or higher in GeneXus Preview Channel (the upcoming GeneXus 15 Upgrade 9) has also the fix.